# DoubleAnimation.Completed event triggered at the end of the Storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, doubleanimation

So I have a `Storyboard` that will run multiple animations one after each other (not all of them simultaneously) and in some of those animations I subscribe to the `DoubleAnimation.Completed` event. The animations run perfectly fine, but the `Completed` event of the animations are only triggered once the whole `Storyboard` is finished, not when the individual animation is finished (`BeginTime` of next animation). For example:

```
Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

DoubleAnimation hideAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
hideAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
hideAnimation.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
hideAnimation.From = 1.0;
hideAnimation.To = 0.0;
hideAnimation.Completed += new EventHandler(HideAnimation_Completed);
Storyboard.SetTarget(hideAnimation, grid1);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(hideAnimation, new PropertyPath(Grid.OpacityProperty));

DoubleAnimation showAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
showAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
showAnimation.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
showAnimation.From = 1.0;
showAnimation.To = 0.0;
showAnimation.Completed += new EventHandler(ShowAnimation_Completed);
Storyboard.SetTarget(showAnimation, grid2);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(showAnimation, new PropertyPath(Grid.OpacityProperty));

storyboard.Children.Add(hideAnimation);
storyboard.Children.Add(showAnimation);
storyboard.Begin();
```

In this example `HideAnimation_Completed` will be called after 1 second (total duration of `storyboard`) and after `HideAnimation_Completed` is done, `ShowAnimation_Completed` is called.

Is was expecting `HideAnimation_Completed` to be called after 0.5 seconds and `ShowAnimation_Completed` after 1 second, not both after 1 second.

Those anyone knows if this an intended behaviour of WPF or am I missing something?

NOTE: The previous code is just an example to explain the problem I have. In my real program I have multiple animations that are dynamically generated and added into a global `Storyboard` at different parts of the the class. So the idea of starting each animation at the end of the previous one using the `Completed` event and `UIElement.BeginAnimation` method, is the last of my resources since that would involve modifying quite a lot of my code (and it would probably have a great effect over the performance of my application).

Comment: How does it behave if you run the animations independently, without a Storyboard? E.g. `grid1.BeginAnimation(Grid.OpacityProperty, hideAnimation);`

Comment: I can't really test individual animations since (as I mentioned in the question) they are dynamically generated on run time with information that comes from different parts of the program. That code in the question is not actual code of my program is just a sample that I type just to help me explain what the problem is (maybe adding that code was a bad idea).

Comment: You can still try if the example you've posted behaves differently if you call BeginAnimation independently, just to get an idea of a possible solution or workaround.

Comment: You are right. If I try I can actually verify if this is an intended behavior or not. Let me try and I let you know how it goes.

Comment: Yes indeed it seems to be an intended behavior in WPF. I just tried the code in a separate application and I still have the same problem.